# Want to know about tag name locator in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I know and use all of the locator except tag name locator. I am confused when and why i use tag name locator also how can i use this locator. I am trying but failed. So please some body help me.

Answer (score 0):

"tagName" is used to identify / find / select WebElement(s) by the HTML tag name.
You can find more information about HTML tag name at this link:[HTML Introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp)

Sample code to find all the anchor tag elements on the Mercury Tours Demo AUT home is page:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TagNameDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\selenium\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    String baseUrl = "http://www.newtours.demoaut.com/";
    driver.get(baseUrl);

    List<WebElement> anchortags = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    for(WebElement anchortag : anchortags)
    {
        System.out.println(anchortag.getText());
    }

    driver.close();
    driver.quit();

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When we have duplicate element locators like classname, id and identified by unique tag name then we can use this locator.
example:

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("a")).findElement(By.xpath(//*[@class='submit'])).click();
```

some web elements are designed only with the tag name and don't have other locators, in that case, we can use tagName locator

when we have dynamic changes in other locator values and difficult to use them. In this scenario, tagName is almost unique and can identify elements easily.